# Как при вводе данных, если не число, выводить сообщение?

Tags: c++

Не получается реализовать проверку на дурака в c++, работает только частично, нужно чтобы при вводе данных, если не число, выводилось сообщение "Повторите попытку" и заново ввод.

```
int workIntUserInput( int inputInt ){

while(true){


    wcin >> inputInt;

    if( !wcin ){

        wcout << L"\nОшибка! Некорректные данные!\n\n";
        wcin.clear();
        while( wcin.get() != '\n' );

    } else break;

}

return inputInt;
```

}
Принимает числа с запятыми, точками, минус буква, минус ноль.
Проверка должна работать при любом бреде - выводить повторный ввод, если же проходит проверку - вернуть значения.
Также были другие попытки написания функции, но они абсолютно не читабельные (пытался реализовать при помощи isdigit, переводил в стринг - по символьна).

Comment: На вход должна подаваться строка со всевозможными символами(знаки препинания, буквы, цифры). Это я понял. Не понятно проверка, на что проверять должна. В каком случае ошибку выводить, а в каком не выводить

Comment: Из вашего описания должна строка входить содержащая все что угодно и проверяться: если натурально число, то все отлично возвращаем значение, если нет, то повторить ввод. Правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот, когда-то подхалтуривал :) -

```
int inputInt(const char * prompt, int m = INT_MIN, int M = INT_MAX)
{
    int N;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << " (целое от " << m << " до " << M << "): " << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> N).good() && (m <= N) && (N <= M)) return N;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Число вне допустимого диапазона значений. Повторите ввод.\n";
        }
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

a = inputInt("Введите размер массива",1,10);
```

Для широких символов, думаю, сами переправите?...